# url rewriting in asp.net in datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

So I have a situation, where I am suppose to add url re-writing in an asp.net web application. The scenario is that I have a datalist, in which I am showing different country names like India, Pakistan, America, Australia, China etc. Now when a user click any of these links, I am sending a country id in the query string. This looks ugly and is not good for SEO as well. So now I am stuck on it. I tried on youtube, but there is no much help for asp.net.

Can anyone guide me to some step by step tutorial for adding url re-writing in asp.net.

I'll be really thankful.

Thanks

Comment: my friend google knows of a good resource on url rewriting http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.net 3.5 sp 1
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx

.net 4
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: These are both routing by the way.  Usually preferable to rewriting.